# compare date and time in JS

Tags: javascript, date, compare

I am authenticating user using oAuth2 which gives me expiry token.

The expiry token is for 3600 (which means one hour, as per oauth standard)

Now, when the token expire, I want to use refresh token to get new access token.

To see if the token have expired, I am thinking about storing the value of current Date.now() and the value of Date.now() after one hour.

THe problem is that `date.now()` gives value in long int i.e

```js
let date = Date.now() 
console.log(date)
```

Now, I am unable to comprehend how I can compare time here. Can somenone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *Date.now* returns a time value and there are always exactly 3.6e6 ms in an ECMAScript hour, you can just add 3.6e6 to get the time value in one hour, e.g.

```js
var now = Date.now();
var expires = now + 3.6e6;

console.log(`expired yet? ${now > expires}`);
console.log(`now    : ${new Date(now).toLocaleString()}\nexpires: ${new Date(expires).toLocaleString()}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `new Date()` intead of Date.now()

as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript
>   Date object for the current date and time according to system settings
>   for timezone offset.

then dates can be directly compared using the `>` and `<` operators

Answer (score 1):

Here an example where compare the date:

```js
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){ //simulation after 1 hour
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}

var dateOld = new Date();
var dateNow = new Date().addHours(1);//test after 1 hour

//output: false
console.log(dateOld.getTime() === dateNow.getTime());//compare the date
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var time=new Date()
var now=String(time.getHours())+":"+String(time.getMinutes())+":"+String(time.getSeconds());
```

This will give you the time in H:M:S.
Format and this will be string.